# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, egg

```
Extracting in C:\Users\hkpra\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3esvodcb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hkpra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-imphcwak\unroll\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    ez_setup.use_setuptools()
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download
    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 99, in _build_egg
    _extractall(tar)
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 467, in _extractall
    self.chown(tarinfo, dirpath)
TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hkpra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-imphcwak\unroll\

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pygame with pip: Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153444/installing-pygame-with-pip-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error)

Answer (score -1):

These are the things you need to do to fix this error when installing python. Make sure to follow in accordance.

1. check if PIP and setuptools are installed.
2. upgrade PIP and setuptools.
3. install ez_setup.

Should you want step by step guidance on how to go about it, you can go [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/command-python-setup-py-egg_info-failed-with-error-code-1).

Answer (score -2):

**install python again, then successed**

I also install by pip,lick

```
pip install locustio
```

or

```
sudo pip install locustio
```

but error occur

> Collecting locustio
>
> Using cached locustio-0.7.5.tar.gz
>
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>
> running egg_info
>
> error: Invalid distribution name or version syntax: locustio-0.7.5
>
> ---
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/yw/15gswkd13v37xjqjy66rc8xc0000gn/T/pip-build-hFFjxs/locustio/

I try pip, pip3, and so on. Finally, I install python again and then it is ok.

for python2.7
`sudo pip install python`

for python3
`sudo pip install python3`