# Installing pygame with pip: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, installation, pygame, pip

I have only recently started to learn programming with python. Currently I am trying to install pygame but I am constantly gettting the same error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-1.9.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

Path for SDL not found.
Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
Path for FONT not found.
Path for IMAGE not found.
Path for MIXER not found.
Path for PNG not found.
Path for JPEG not found.
Path for PORTMIDI not found.
Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


Continuing With "setup.py"
Error with the "Setup" file,
perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\filip\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-0xsf1b\pygame\setup.py", line 165, in <module>
    extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\extension.py", line 164, in read_setup_file
    line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 430, in expand_makefile_vars
    s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\filip\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-0xsf1b\pygame\
```

I already went through a number of posts with similar problems but none of them had the exactly same issue, and/or they were concerned with different packages and operating systems. Moreover, I tried a couple of solutions to those problems but nothing worked for me (i tried upgrading pip, installing with easy_install and some other options I, unfortunately, cannot even recall at this point...).

I would be sincerely grateful if someone can help me with this problem. I am aware that it is possibly an irrelevant or "newbie" question, but I honestly tried finding a solution on my own and really have no more clue what to do. I have also never been really educated in computer science, so all of these things frustrate and confuse the hell out of me and constantly get in the way of the learning process (which is hard enough).

I am using Windows 10, python 3.3 64-bit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to install pygame, which worked for me (W10 64bit, Python 3.4.5).

Head [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and download the correct pygame wheel file for your version. Then, from cmd, go to the directory the file is in, and type `pip install [COMPLETE EXACT FILENAME]`.

Good luck!

Comment: Could you please help me in determining which is the correct one? I only understand the win32 and 64 part..

Comment: @Fichonije If your python version is 3.3, the website sadly doesn't provide the exact version, but can try the cp34 (python 3.4) amd_64 one, although I don't think it will work with your 3.3. You could either search the web for another website, or just update to python 3.4.2, and use the same file (the differences between your version and this one are very minor, just bugfixes, so all your current scripts should work)

Comment: I tried and it didn't work.. I was trying to avoid using another version since I am not sure it will work with pyscripter, which I got used to. And it brings a whole other area of "setting up things" which I don't fully understand yet.. Thanks a lot for your help anyway, really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Fichonije I use PyScripter too :). I can testify that it works with python 3.4. However, I understand that it may be annoying to make the transition. Sorry that I wasn't able to help you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but i solved it by updating pip

Answer (score 2):

Try install pygame from this repository: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

It is not a official place, but it is trusted. I was having this same problem, and I resolved it installing the package (pygame) from this website. You just have to download the intended".whl" file and install with "pip" from the place where your download is placed.

Don't forget uninstall the previous Pygame installed. =)

Comment: I tried but there's no file for 3.3... Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading `pip`. Simply open your command line (search `cmd` in your task bar search box) and enter the command below:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade your Python version. Uninstall your current Python and delete uninstalled python folder, then install python3.5.

Last, you can use the command line:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed too.

Answer (score -1):

Check your mysql configuration file using this:

```
mysql_config
```

Now you should get an output something like this:

```
mysql_config 
Usage: /usr/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Compiler: GNU 6.3.0
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/usr/include/mysql ]
        --cxxflags       [-I/usr/include/mysql ]
        --include        [-I/usr/include/mysql]
        --libs           [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -ldl]
        --libs_r         [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -ldl]
        --plugindir      [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
        --socket         [/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [5.7.18]
        --libmysqld-libs [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqld -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lcrypt -ldl -laio -llz4 -lnuma]
        --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
                pkgincludedir [/usr/include/mysql]
                pkglibdir     [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
                plugindir     [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
```

Ideally it should contain *libmysqld-libs* option. If it is not there, as it was not there in my case, you can assume that your mysql is broken.

In this case you can write this configuration to config file directly

Comment: whats your meaning of `you can write this configuration to config file directly`?