# Installing pygame through pip error

Tags: python, pygame, pip, command-prompt

I'm trying to install pygame to work with python through pip, however when I use the command pip install pygame, it begins working and seems alright until it throws an error. This is the output I get, I'm not sure if i'm doing it correctly or what, I'm new to pip so I'm just not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

```
C:\Users\Matthew>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...

    Path for SDL not found.
    Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
    Path for FONT not found.
    Path for IMAGE not found.
    Path for MIXER not found.
    Path for PNG not found.
    Path for JPEG not found.
    Path for PORTMIDI not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

    If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
    the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


    Continuing With "setup.py"
    Error with the "Setup" file,
    perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kzk4_t2_\pygame\setup.
py", line 165, in <module>
        extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
      File "c:\users\matthew\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distu
tils\extension.py", line 171, in read_setup_file
        line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
      File "c:\users\matthew\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distu
tils\sysconfig.py", line 410, in expand_makefile_vars
        s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
    TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Matthew\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kzk4_t2_\pygame\
```

Comment: PyGame uses library [SDL 1.2](http://libsdl.org/) so maybe try to install it.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153444/installing-pygame-with-pip-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error). It helped me. Good luck!

Comment: Did Andrew's comment help you? If so, please close this question, thnx!

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but the error is usually related with incompatible versions of Python and PyGame. You should check if the version of Python you're using is compatible with the version of PyGame.

You may need to install a specific version of PyGame, e.g. `python -m pip install pygame==1.9.3`

I've been using PyGame 1.9.3 with Python 3.6.8 and it's working just fine

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Nov. 2022), Python v. 3.11 for Windows x64 is incompatible with the current version of Pygame (2.1.2). In order to make it work, you have to roll back to Python 3.10.2 (confirmed through testing).