# Error installing pygame python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, django, pip, pygame

It seems the problem lies within the setup paths? Can anyone tell me how to even understand my errors? It won't let me install pygame. Here is the terminal window output once I enter `python -m pip install --user pygame`.

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/6b/c510f0853765eb2219ca5aa3d416d65bb0dea7cd9bb2984aea0a0e04c24d/pygame-1.9.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...

    Path for SDL not found.
    Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
    Path for FONT not found.
    Path for IMAGE not found.
    Path for MIXER not found.
    Path for PNG not found.
    Path for JPEG not found.
    Path for PORTMIDI not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

    If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
    the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


    Continuing With "setup.py"
    Error with the "Setup" file,
    perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b12x3pbp\pygame\setup.py:321: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
      return ', '.join(s for s in findall('\d+', ver)[0:3])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b12x3pbp\pygame\setup.py", line 203, in <module>
        extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
      File "C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Python 3.7\lib\distutils\extension.py", line 171, in read_setup_file
        line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
      File "C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Python 3.7\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 405, in expand_makefile_vars
        s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b12x3pbp\pygame\
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pygame with pip: Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153444/installing-pygame-with-pip-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpygame%5D+TypeError%3A+can+only+concatenate+str+NoneType

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

or

```
python -m pip install
```

if none of these work try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153444/installing-pygame-with-pip-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error) question, the answer should be marked below the question.. I think you have the same issue