# Getting Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when installing via pip

Tags: python, pip, installation, conda

Sorry, I know this has been asked before but my score is too low to comment unfortunately.

I´m working on Mac & getting this error when trying to install a package in conda:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/protos-research/protos-edge.git
```

Already updated setup.py, but didn't make a difference..
Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: What error are you getting, and where has it been asked before?

Comment: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
e.g.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902174/command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981793/python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The repository](https://github.com/protos-research/protos-edge/tree/fc9479d24d5bafe65939cd657dff1c583ca6551d) lacks `setup.py` hence it's not pip-installable. Clone it or download it, create a subdirectory in `site-packages/` and copy the code there manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, stumbled on the next Error however:  

  
`RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please install python.app and replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. See 'Working with Matplotlib on OSX' in the Matplotlib FAQ for more information.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+matplotlib+Python+is+not+installed+as+a+framework